# PHP, HTML filter

Tags: php, html, select

i would like this select filter to show up only if Language count is more than 4
Any ideas?

Here is html select filter code:

```
<p>
Select date:
</p>
<form method="get" action="">
<select id="training_session" name="date"onchange=this.form.submit()>
<option value=""<?php if($_GET['date'] === '') echo 'selected' ?>>[All dates]</option>
<option value="April"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'April') echo 'selected' ?>>April</option>
<option value="May"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'May') echo 'selected' ?>>May</option>
<option value="June"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'June') echo 'selected' ?>>June</option>
<option value="July"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'July') echo 'selected' ?>>July</option>
<option value="August"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'August') echo 'selected' ?>>August</option>
<option value="September"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'September') echo 'selected' ?>>September</option>
<option value="October"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'October') echo 'selected' ?>>October</option>
<option value="November"<?php if($_GET['date'] === 'November') echo 'selected' ?>>November</option>
</form>
<noscript><input type="hidden" value="filter"></noscript>
```

Here is PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date']) {
     foreach ($training_sessions as $key => $session) {
        if (date('F', strtotime($session['ZCS_b_date'])) !== $_GET['date']) {
            unset($training_sessions[$key]);
```

So how do i make it to show up only if language count is more than 4. I have language select filter which has to stay there all the time, but i want date filter to show up only if language count is more than 4.

This is the language select filter code:

```
<p>
Select language:
</p>

<form method="get" action="">
<select id="training_session" name="lang" onchange=this.form.submit()>
<option value=""<?php if($_GET['lang'] === '') echo 'selected' ?>>[All languages]</option>
<option value="English" <?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'English') echo 'selected' ?>>English</option>
<option value="Portuguese"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Portuguese') echo 'selected' ?>>Portuguese</option>
<option value="French"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'French') echo 'selected' ?>>French</option>
<option value="Italian"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Italian') echo 'selected' ?>>Italian</option>
<option value="Japanese"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Japanese') echo 'selected' ?>>Japanese</option>
</form>
<noscript><input type="hidden" value="filter"></noscript>
```

This is the php code for language select filter:

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang']) {
     foreach ($training_sessions as $key => $session) {
        if ($session['training_language'] !== $_GET['lang']) {
            unset($training_sessions[$key]);
```

So does anyone knows what im trying to achieve here? What i want to do.

Comment: No one can help me? :(

Comment: Should i use php if count? what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here we go..
This should give you the results you want

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

   <form id="submitquery" method="get" action="">

   <?php

      $month=array('[All Dates]','January','February','March','April',
                   'May','June','July','August',
                   'September','October','November','December');

      $language=array('[All Languages]','English','Portuguese','French','Italian','Japanese');

      $changeLanguagejs='changeForm();';
      $changeDatejs='this.form.submit();';

      writeSelect($language,'Language',$changeLanguagejs); 

      if (isset($_GET['Language'])){        
         if($_GET['Language']!='[All Languages]'){
            $training_sessions=filterLanguage($training_sessions);}

      if (count($training_sessions)>=4){
         writeSelect($month,'Date',$changeDatejs);
         if (isset($_GET['Date'])){
            if($_GET['Date']!='[All Dates]'){
               $training_sessions=filterDate($training_sessions);}
         showResults($training_sessions);}}
      else{showResults($training_sessions);}}

   ?>

   </form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

   function writeSelect($values,$name,$changejs){
      echo "\n".'<p>Select '.$name.':</p>';
      echo "\n".'   <select id="training_sessions_'.$name.'" name="'.$name.'"  onchange='.$changejs.'>'."\n";
      foreach($values as $value){               
         echo '      <option value="'.$value.'" ';              
         if (isset($_GET[$name]) && $_GET[$name]==$value){echo 'selected ';}
         echo '>'.$value.'</option>'."\n";}
      echo '   </select><br/><br/>'."\n";} 

   function filterLanguage($training_sessions){
      foreach($training_sessions as $key => $session){
         if($session['training_language']!=$_GET['Language']){
            unset($training_sessions[$key]);}}
      return $training_sessions;}

   function filterDate($training_sessions){
      foreach($training_sessions as $key => $session){
         if(date('F', strtotime($session['ZCS_b_date']))!=$_GET['Date']){
            unset($training_sessions[$key]);}}
      return $training_sessions;}

   function showResults($training_sessions){
      echo "\n".'Showing '.count($training_sessions).' ';
      if(count($training_sessions)==1){echo 'Result';}
      else{echo 'Results';}
      echo'<br/>'."\n\n";
      print_r($training_sessions);}

?>

<script>

   function changeForm(){
      var selectLang = document.getElementById("training_sessions_Language").value;
      document.getElementById("submitquery").method="post";
      document.getElementById("submitquery").action="?Language="+selectLang;
      document.getElementById("submitquery").submit();}

</script>
```

I'm going to edit out the comments to make it more readable...
if you want to see the comments go back through the edits of this answer

Comment: Hmm i will try your code. how do i explain it. For example i have a table With person names, with language they know, job they do, and a month when they started doing that. I have dropdown filter for language they know. What i want to do is, when there are more than 4 persons who know English for example. I would like that there appears a new filter who can filter by month. Im trying to figure this out for a while. Do you now understand what im trying to do here?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense... I will edit my answer later when I get a chance

Comment: Thanks a lot, gonna be patient. :)

Comment: That should do the trick.. let me know if I've misunderstood or you need further assistance

Comment: Thanks a lot i will test it out tomorrow. I will reply to you if it worked. :)

Comment: I had a little time this morning so i quickly put in a javascript function for the onchange event of the 'language filter' drop down box. Now when you choose a language, it only passes a language parameter and not a date parameter as well (effective resetting the form) Doing this also allowed me to simplify the rest of the code a little..

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are gold. You just helped me a lot :)

Comment: I have problem in this line:         if($session['training_language']!=$_GET['Language']){
Undefined index: training_language

Comment: This depends on how your $training_session array is defined.. (you didn't include this in you question so I left it how it was)

Comment: Any ideas how to stop it from reloading from top when i choose options?

Comment: I would like to click it and so that it would just stay at place